# stack rasters with different extent and resolution in a loop with R package raster

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, stack

I would like to stack rasters with the R package "raster". Layers are in ascii format. I want to crop them to have the same extent and project them to have the same resolution. My code gives raster layers with empty values.

```
#The layers must have a similar extent and projection. We will first crop them all to the same extent.
#Read files found in the working directory containing *.asc
raster_data <- list.files(pattern='*.asc', full.names=TRUE)
#get desired extent (smallest raster extent)
e <- extent(-12, 112, 23, 72)
#get template layer with desired extent and resolution. Transform ascii template layer to raster format
d <- raster("WC_BIO1.asc", ext = e, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0", ncol=15120, nrow=6000)
w <- writeRaster(d, "WC_BIO1_template.grd", format = "raster")
#load ascii layers, transform to raster format with extent and resolution obtained from template layer
for (i in 1:length(raster_data)){
  r <- raster(raster_data[i], crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
  rc <- crop(r, e)
  rp <- projectRaster(from = rc, to = w,
                      crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0",
                      filename = file.path ("./crop", raster_data[i]),
                      method = "bilinear",
                      format = "raster",
                      overwrite = TRUE)
  rw <- writeRaster(rp,
                    filename = file.path ("./crop", raster_data[i]),
                    crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0",
                    overwrite = TRUE,
                    format = "raster",
                    na.value=-9999)
  }
```

Comment: `resample` from the **raster** package has been designed for this particular purpose. Inside the loop, use `rp <- projectRaster(r, w)` before running `resample(rp, w)`. As far as I can tell, the use of `crop` is not required.

Comment: @fdetsch is right on the mark. You do not want to use projectRaster. This funciton is for transforming the projection space of the raster and not subsetting or resampling. Also, wildcards using "*" do not produce the expected results in list.files and you are missing the path argument. This should be a regular expression and would looks like: list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "asc$")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints. It is difficult to answer without knowing more about your data. Please show us the result of:

```
raster(raster_data[1])
```

- You pass arguments to the `raster` function that are ignored when you create an object from file. You do not need to use `crop` on this layer. Certainly not *before* you project the data to lon/lat.
- You never need projectRaster AND resample. If your layers are indeed lon/lat use `resample` or, if possible, just `crop` and `(dis)aggregate`.
- My impression is that they are not lon/lat. This may be the problem and the reason that your layers are empty. In that case you must assign the correct current CRS to them, before using projectRaster. In projectRaster do not use the crs argument (it is ignored anyway, as the CRS from w is used).
- Do not use writeRaster, as you are already saving the file with projectRaster (or could do so with resample). Also writeRaster does not have arguments crs and na.value, so these are ignored.

Here is the fixed code:

```
raster_data <- list.files(pattern='\\.asc$', full.names=TRUE)
w <- raster("WC_BIO1.asc", crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84")

for (i in 1:length(raster_data)){
    r <- raster(raster_data[i], crs="???????")
    rp <- projectRaster(from = rc, to = w,
                      filename = file.path ("./crop", raster_data[i]),
                      method = "bilinear",
                      format = "raster",
                      overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: I didn't know `projectRaster` includes spatial resampling when 'to' is specified. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Here is the result of `raster(raster_data[1])`
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 199, 503, 100097  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : -13, 112.75, 23, 72.75  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : ...
names       : CMSAF_SDL  
  > As you can see my dataset do not have crs so I used: `crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" ` ...@fdetsch solution also worked well, but I guess that your code is the right way to do it.

Comment: No, in that case `projectRaster` is not the way to go, but you should indeed use `resample`; or a combination of `disaggregate` and `crop`